# Removing lines that have strings with same hexadecimal values from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file **in1.txt**

```
info="0x0000b573" data="0x7" id="sp. PCU(Si)"
info="0x0000b573" data="0x00000007" id="HI all. SHa"
info="0x00010AC3" data="0x00000003" id="abc_16. PS"
info="0x00010ac3" data="0x00000045" id="hB2_RC/BS (Spr)"
info="0x205" data="0x00000010" id="cgc_15. PK"
info="0x205" data="0x10" id="cgsd_GH/BS (Scd)"
```

Expected output: **out.txt**

```
info="0x00010AC3" data="0x00000003" id="abc_16. PS"
info="0x00010ac3" data="0x00000045" id="hB2_RC/BS (Spr)"
```

I need only lines that have same **info** values and different **data** values to be written to out.txt.

but the current code removes all the line that have string data in it.

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as fin,open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if 'data' not in line:
            fout.write(line.strip()+'\n')
```

what i need is for eg: line 1 and line 2 is having same `info="0x0000b573"` and data is `"0x7" & "0x00000007`" which is same then remove that line.

Comment: Are lines having same info consecutive ? As it is the case in your sample file.

Comment: yes same infos.

Comment: You have to iterate over your lines while keeping the previous info.
Before the loop, initialize previous to None.
In the loop you need to extract info, then compare the current with the previous (case sensitive).
Don't forget at the end of each iteration to set previous to the current info, in order to prepare the next iteration.
The rest of the logic should be quite basic.

Comment: The issue is here :`if 'data' not in line`.
That condition is true if the word`data` is absent in the line (you don't look at the value).
As you have a data field for each line, every lines are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`

```py
import re

s = '''info="0x0000b573" data="0x7" id="sp. PCU(Si)"
info="0x0000b573" data="0x00000007" id="HI all. SHa"
info="0x00010AC3" data="0x00000003" id="abc_16. PS"
info="0x00010ac3" data="0x00000045" id="hB2_RC/BS (Spr)"
info="0x205" data="0x00000010" id="cgc_15. PK"
info="0x205" data="0x10" id="cgsd_GH/BS (Scd)"'''

parsed_data = re.findall(r'info="([^"]+)" data="([^"]+)" id="[^"]+"', s, re.MULTILINE)
parsed_data = sorted([list(map(lambda x: int(x, 16), i)) + [index] for index,i in enumerate(parsed_data)])

row_numbers = [j for i in [[parsed_data[i][-1], parsed_data[i+1][-1]] for i in range(0,len(parsed_data),2) if parsed_data[i][1] != parsed_data[i+1][1]] for j in i]


final_output = []

for index,line in enumerate(s.split('\n')):
    if index in row_numbers:
        final_output.append(line)
        
        
final_out_text = '\n'.join(final_output)
print(final_out_text)

# info="0x00010AC3" data="0x00000003" id="abc_16. PS"
# info="0x00010ac3" data="0x00000045" id="hB2_RC/BS (Spr)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that too, I think

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

records = {}
items = []
info = []
data = []

with open("in.dat", "r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        items=line.split(' ')
        info = items[0].split('=')
        data = items[1].split('=')
        try:
            key = info[1].strip('"').lower()
            value = str(int(data[1].strip('"'), 16))
            records[key][value] += 1
        except KeyError:
            try:
                records[key][value] = 1
            except KeyError:
                records[key] = {value: 1}


out = dict()
for key in records:
    for value in records[key]:
        if records[key][value] == 1:
            try:
                out[key].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                out[key] = [value]
             

with open("out.dat", "w") as fout:
    for key in out:
        for value in out[key]:
            fout.write(f"{key}={value}\n")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
found_info_values = []

with open("in.txt", "r") as fin,open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        info = line.split('"')[1]
        if info not in found_info_values:
            fout.write(line.strip()+'\n')
        found_info_values += info
```